# Kotlin factory interface with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, factory

I have a factory interface in my Kotlin code, like so (using Guava's [`TypeToken`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken)):

```
interface ResultMapperFactory {
    fun <T> get(type: TypeToken<T>, context: MapperLookupContext): ResultMapper<T>?
}
```

So far, so good. This is very easy to use when calling it, however implementation almost always requires an unsafe cast:

```
object StringFactory : ResultMapperFactory {
    override fun <T> get(type: TypeToken<T>, context: MapperLookupContext): ResultMapper<T>? {
        return if (type.rawType == String::class.java) MyStringMapper as ResultMapper<T> else null
    }
}
```

This is ugly, but I have overcome it with a nice trick. First, a little utility function for creating `TypeToken` instances:

```
inline fun <reified T> typeToken(): TypeToken<T> = object : TypeToken<T>() {}
```

Now I added a companion object to my factory interface:

```
companion object {

    inline operator fun <reified R> invoke(crossinline body: (TypeToken<R>, MapperLookupContext) -> ResultMapper<R>?): ResultMapperFactory {
        val t = typeToken<R>().type
        return object : ResultMapperFactory {
            override fun <T> get(type: TypeToken<T>, context: MapperLookupContext): ResultMapper<T>? {
                return if (type.isSubtypeOf(t)) body(type as TypeToken<R>, context) as ResultMapper<T>? else null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to have the unchecked (but safe) cast in one place and I can write code like the following:

```
val stringMapper: ResultMapper<String> = TODO()
val stringMapperFactory = ResultMapperFactory<String> { type, context ->
    stringMapper
}
```

However this approach also falls apart as soon as I want to implement a factory that takes a `TypeToken<List<T>>` and returns a `ResultMapper<List<T>>`, because there is nowhere for me to put that `T` parameter.

I am eager to hear your suggestions.

Comment: You mean where `T` is not a concrete type?

Comment: Exactly. I would want to write a factory that creates a mapper for `List<T>` for any `T`. This is possible because the factory can look up how to map the elements of type `T` with the `MapperLookupContext`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself, using the `invoke` operator fun I posted in my original question I can write the following:

```
private class ListResultMapper<out E>(private val elementMapper: ResultMapper<E>) : ResultMapper<List<E>> { /* ... */ }

val listMapperFactory = ResultMapperFactory<List<*>> { type, context -> context.resultMapperFactory.get(type.elementType(), context)?.let { ListResultMapper(it) } }
```